# How to sort out elements by their value in data- attribute using JS

Tags: javascript, sorting, appendchild

I need to sort out the elements that are already displayed in ascending order so that they just rearrange. I need to sort them out by the values in their data-val attributes.

```
<div id="a" class="item" data-val="6">Item a</div>
<div id="b" class="item" data-val="8">Item b</div>
<div id="c" class="item" data-val="2">Item c</div>
<div id="d" class="item" data-val="5">Item d</div>

<br />
<button onclick="sortOut()">Sort Out</button>
```

I made an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/quatzael/uKnpa/

I dont know how to do that. I kind of started but it is probably wrong.

I need the function to firstly find out what elements have class called "item" and then those with this class sort out by the value of their data-val attribute.

It has to work in all browsers so the solution should probably involve .appendChild()

Tnx for any help..

Comment: You can check my answer to a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71378596/how-to-reorder-a-html-list-with-jquery-after-a-button-click/71378855#71378855

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to append them to the DOM in the newly sorted order.

Here's what I added to your code to do this:

```
divs.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.dataset.val.localeCompare(b.dataset.val);
});

var br = document.getElementsByTagName("br")[0];

divs.forEach(function(el) {
    document.body.insertBefore(el, br);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RZ2K4/

The `appendChild()` method could be used instead of `.insertBefore()` if your sorted items were in a container with nothing else.

To support older browsers, you would use `.getAttribute("data-val")` instead of `.dataset.val`.

And if you want a numeric sorting, you shouldn't use `.localeCompare` in the `.sort()` function.

Comment: In that case, use `return +a.dataset.val - +b.dataset.val;`

Comment: I amended it and it is still not working.. [http://jsfiddle.net/quatzael/RZ2K4/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/quatzael/RZ2K4/2/)

Comment: @user1850012: Working here, in FF and Chrome. Order is correct both using `localeComapre` and `+a.dataset.val`.

Comment: Now its working!!! Thanks a lot!!
[http://jsfiddle.net/RZ2K4/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/RZ2K4/3/)

Answer (score 0):

you can add `flex` property for the wrapper and use `order` to order them.
or you can reappend elements to their parent

[Demo](https://codepen.io/zuhairtaha/pen/gOrvobj?editors=1111)

```js
const items = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("li"));
const btn = document.querySelector("button");
const orderBy = Array(5).fill().map((x, i) => i + 1); // [1..5]

btn.addEventListener("click", clickHander);
function clickHander() {
  orderBy.forEach(i => {
    const item = items.find(x => x.getAttribute("data-order") === `${i}`);
    item.style.order = i;
    // OR: item.parentElement.appendChild(item);
  });
}
```

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li data-order="4">order 4</li>
  <li data-order="3">order 3</li>
  <li data-order="1">order 1</li>
  <li data-order="5">order 5</li>
  <li data-order="2">order 2</li>
</ul>
<button>sort</button>
```