# Sort HTML String

Tags: javascript, html

I have this bit of HTML code.

```
<div class="container">

 <div class="single-result">
  <span class="flight-no">VL2100</span>
  <span class="cabin">Economy</span>
  <span class="price">35000</span>
 </div>

 <div class="single-result">
  <span class="flight-no">VL2101</span>
  <span class="cabin">Economy</span>
  <span class="price">40000</span>
 </div>

 <div class="single-result">
  <span class="flight-no">VL2100</span>
  <span class="cabin">Economy</span>
  <span class="price">22000</span>
 </div>

 <div class="single-result">
  <span class="flight-no">VL2100</span>
  <span class="cabin">Economy</span>
  <span class="price">14500</span>
 </div>

</div>
```

How do I sort it -- based on `price` -- using Javascript? Please, don't ask me for my JS code. My only thought was to use the [bubble sort algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16956649/javascript-bubble-sort-of-an-array-with-objects). But then, bubble sort works only on sorted arrays and my HTML string isn't sorted. Any suggestions, pointers and / or code will be appreciated.

Comment: sort the elements based on what

Comment: Why can't we see your code?

Comment: @ArunPJohny I assume they mean `.single-result`

Comment: @ArunPJohny, oops!!! my bad, sort it based on price. Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14131008/how-to-sort-out-elements-by-their-value-in-data-attribute-using-js

Comment: Pretty straight forward really -> http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/p0Lkw81j/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an array and insert for each element 2 fields, the HTML element and the price, sort the array, re-insert the elements after sorting to conainer after make it empty:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.single-result');

var sortable = [];
for (i=0;i<elements.length;i++){
  sortable.push([elements[i], elements[i].querySelector('.price').textContent]);
}

sortable.sort(function(a, b) {return a[1] - b[1]});

container = document.querySelector('.container');
container.innerHTML = "";

sortable.forEach(function(item) {
  container.appendChild(item[0]);
});
```